# Is there a script somewhere that can scrape hotmail web page for simple things like unread count?

Tags: html, scripting, email, live, hotmail

Is there a script somewhere (doesn't matter what language although it would be best if it can run on linux) that can fetch for simple things from the hotmail/live mail web page? Of course the main motivation for this is that hotmail does not allow for IMAP access and their pop access is limited to 15 minute check and YET still does not provide an unread count.

Ideally, this script can get a bit more information like the more recent unread mail and that would be perfect! I would then fetch for these information from my software through repeatedly calling this script.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at 'getlive' and 'gotmail' packages ;)